# New feature MEF in .net 4.0

Tags: .net, frameworks

Managed Extensibility Framework is the new feature of .net 4.0. What is it ? and How to use it in our existing application ?

Comment: Surely you mean "whether to use it in our existing application"?

Comment: yes, i have an win form application and have a lot of dll for different component. Now in my application these dlls are reusable. So as i read about MEF that it enables greater reuse of applications and components. So My question is that How MEF is suitable in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a "add-in" framework which is designed to let add-ins customize a lot of things in your application. Visual Studio 2010 extension architecture is build with MEF which should give you an idea of how "extensible" it is (look at how different the extensions for VS 2010 is).

Take a look on this article:

[Building Composable Apps in .NET 4 with the Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx)

Description from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef (which contains the source code):

*The Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) is a new library in .NET that enables greater reuse of applications and components. Using MEF, .NET applications can make the shift from being statically compiled to dynamically composed. **If you are building extensible applications, extensible frameworks and application extensions, then MEF is for you.***

Comment: thanks for links. I went through it partially. My question is still there which u can read above.